# How do I make a HSQLDB 2 client program?

Tags: java, netbeans, hsqldb

I have a small HSQLDB program to test bits of SQL.  I am getting this error:

```
 A pre-version 2.0 client attempted to connect.  We rejected them.
```

Yet the only JDBC driver I have is the HSQLDB v2.3 in the most recent download:

```
hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar
```

I'm using this string to load the JDBC driver:

```
 Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
```

And the connection string is:

```
 connectionStr = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/tmp_db";
 user=sa, password=
```

Default values.  My HSQLDB server seems to have started OK with a database as follows:

```
 server.dbname.0=**tmp_db**
 server.database.0=file:r:/.data/hsqldb/**tmp_db/tmp**
[Server@372f7a8d]: Database [index=2, id=2, db=file:r:/.data/hsqldb/**tmp_db/tmp**, alias=tmp_db] opened sucessfully in 26 ms.
```

I'm using Netbeans and when I connect via the Services tab, the database seems to be opening OK.  Wouldn't Netbeans be using the same driver?  Can I check that?

The big question is how do we specify the version 2 client connection, driver or parameters?  Must I get a different JAR for the correct driver?

One last thing.  The test program works fine if I use a file based connection, such as:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:db_file
```

Frustratingly too, the server connection string seemed to be working earlier today.  At least I could drop/create tables while I was making changes.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the same jars (or at least recent, compatible versions) on the client and server.

The error shows you are using the 2.x version jar on the server but a 1.8 jar on the client. Check NetBeans to see if some extension you have loaded has the old driver. You can use the correct jar in your NetBeans project by adding it as a library.

If the error is not from NetBeans, check your application's classpath and make sure you have the latest jar in it.